# Android Global touch event

Tags: android, service, touch

I'm making a background app A in android, and want to catch the touch event on the screen.
Because the foreground app B (currently running one) is not my app,
I can't use the intent for inter-app communication.

Can I read the touch sensing information like other GPS or Accelerometer sensors, using public API, hooking(?), even in a low-level from the capacitive touch screen, or in any way? (given the user allowed any permission but rooting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, this is not possible, for obvious security and privacy reasons.

Comment: that's sad, it would be super awesome for usability testing

Comment: @VahurRoosimaa: For usability testing, it is your own app, not arbitrary third-party apps.